# ExtJS: validitychange - exclude hidden input fields from validity check

Tags: extjs, formpanel, checkvalidity

I have a form with two input fields 'test1' and 'test2' and one combo box. I want to validate this form, the input fields should be not emtpy. I use therefore the config ' allowBlank: false' and the controller method 'onFormValidityChanged'. This works fine.

Now I hide the input field 'test2' when I change the value in the combo box with the controller method 'onChangeCombo' dynamically. Also, I set config ' allowBlank: true' of input field 'test2'. But my form is not valid when the hidden input field 'test2' is empty.

How can I exclude the hidden input field from the validity check?

I use the ExtJS version 6.6.

Thank you for your hints, Thomas

View:

```
    items : [{
        xtype : ' formpanel',
        trackResetOnLoad : true,            
        layout : {
            type : 'vbox',
            align : 'stretch'
        },
        items : [
        {
            xtype : ' textfield',
            name : 'test1'
            itemId : 'test1',
            allowBlank : false,
            fieldLabel : 'test1'
        },
        {
            xtype : ' combobox',
            name : 'combo',
            itemId : 'combo',
            store: myStore,
            listeners : {
                change : 'onChangeCombo'
            }
        },            
        {
            xtype : ' textfield',
            name : 'test2'
            itemId : 'test2',
            allowBlank : false,
            fieldLabel : 'test2'
        }],
        listeners : {
            validitychange : 'onFormValidityChanged'
        }
    }];
```

Controller:

```
onFormValidityChanged : function(form, valid) {
    var win, button;
    win = form.owner.up('window');
    button = win.down('[xtype=button]');
    button.setDisabled(!valid);
}, 

onChangeCombo : function(combobox) {
    var win, test2;
    win = combobox.up('window');
    test2 = win.down('textfield[itemId=test2]');
    test2.hide();
    test2.allowBlank = true;
}
```

Comment: @norbeq's answer is correct but I also have a suggestion for you: Use the button's `formBind` property. With it you will not need the `onFormValidityChanged` method.
"When inside FormPanel, any component configured with formBind: true will be enabled / disabled depending on the validity state of the form." Look [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#cfg-formBind).

Answer (score 1):

to turn off the validation, just disable this hidden input.

`test2.disable();`

I have a suggestion for You too:

- use test2.setAllowBlank(true) instead of test2.allowBlank = true
- don't use reference like win.down(etc.), check out the ViewController options with reference and lookup method

Answer (score 0):

Norbeq's proposal

```
test2.disable()
```

get not provide a solution. I don't know why...

I did not follow the dh117's formBind suggestion.
I solved this problem as follows:

```
test2 = win('textfield[itemId=test2]');
win.remove(test2);
```

Thank you for your hints, also for the further hints,
Thomas